# Как залить несколько веток на гитхаб?

Tags: git, github

Я делаю свои пет проекты и у меня две ветки: master и моя dev, когда в ветке дев все ок то я их смердживаю. Как только я связываю проект с гитхабом таким образом:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Example/Example.git
$ git branch -M main
$ git push -u origin main
```

то когда я делаю пуш у меня все комиты идут в одной ветке и мне подсказали что это плохая практика и нужно заливать обе ветки и так же их смердживать чтоб было видно на гитхабе а не локально. Как это сделать ?

Comment: аналогично: `$ git push -u origin dev`

Comment: Если вы работаете не в команде, то в принципе нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы работать в одной ветке.

Comment: Понял, благодарю. А как их смерджить на гитхабе ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На гитхабе вы в любом случае будете видеть такую же историю, что и локально. Нет смысла делать слияние средствами гитхаба, если у вас есть права коммитить напрямую в main. Если нет прав, то слияние делается через Pull Request.

А все ветки отправляются одной командой `git push -u --all origin`